# When user.private_tempstore gets deleted

Tags: 8, sessions

I've read about the

> \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');

and found similar to storing data in $_SESSION.

I am using user.private_tempstore in my module to store some data related to the user for a current session but when I logout and login again to the system found the value still persist in that variable. It is supposed to delete on logout.

To store data

```
  $userSession = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('user_profile');
  $userSession->set('user_profile', TRUE);
```

To get data

```
  $userSession = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('user_profile');
  $user_profile = $userSession->get('user_profile');
```

Is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Private tempstore data isn't deleted when you log out, it is usually deleted after a predefined, fixed amount of time.

If you want data that is deleted on logout, then either store in the session or store it somewhere with a random key that you put into a session (Useful when it is data that is no commonly needed on every request and/or larger than just a simple scalar value)